# public IEnumerable <entityClass> set to Linq query, returns null - Asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ienumerable

I have a web page that will make frequent calls to a data source. Instead of sending many calls to a database, I want to localize the set and then make the various controls query the local set using linq. I may be trying to do this all wrong, so I'm looking for some input.

```
private IEnumerable<entityFrameworkClass> _theList;
private IEnumerable<entityFrameworkClass> theList
{ set { _theList = from i in context select i;} get { return _theList; }}
```

Then in Page_Load

```
var yearQuery = from y in theList
                     select y;
```

I get an error that the source is null during debug.

Any ideas or maybe recommendations for a better method to accomplish this?

Comment: Personal Preference Warning: `var yearQuery = from y in theList select y` is waaaay longer than it needs to be (and unnecessarily verbose).  just `var yearQuery = theList` will do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the inner private variable `_theList` in the `set` of `theList` property but when reading it, it's the `get` that will be accessed ([Properties in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)).

What you want to do is this (Try also to write properties with CamelCase[[Capitalization Conventions]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)):

```
private IEnumerable<entityFrameworkClass> TheList
{ 
    get
    { 
        if(_theList == null)
        {
             _theList = from i in context select i;
        }
        return _theList; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code above the "set" is never getting called hence your _theList is empty
I would also change it to:

```
_theList = (from i in context select i).ToList();
```

To ensure it gets called now -without deferred execution